# Enzyme sub element has no 'find()'

Tags: enzyme

I have a simple test where I am searching on '.shop' elements, returning two of them, and then I want to get the first element and look at an embedded element : '.shop__title'.

See code :

```
describe('Shop Page', () => {
    let wrapper

    let store = createStore(reducers, mockStoreData);

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Dashboard />
            </Provider>,
        );
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.unmount();
    });


    it('test ', () => {
        let elems = wrapper.find('.shop');
        expect(elems.length).toBe(2); //yes, i have two shops!

        let e = elems.get(0);
        e.find('.shop__title') //find function does not exist!!!
    })
});
```

I am not quite sure what this 'e' element is (the first element in the array that I am looking at), but my IDE shows me this :

[image]

What sort of object is this? How do I get the 'find' and 'simulate' functions working on this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`at`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/at.html) instead of [`get`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/get.html)

```
let e = elems.at(0);
e.find('.shop__title') //find function does not exist!!!
```

The problem is `get` returns you the `ReactElement` but `at` returns a `ShallowWrapper` which has the `find` method.